# onTouchEvent in a BaseAdapter Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-view

In my program I must insert this onTouchEvent method in a BaseAdapter component:

```
    public class FlipAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        ...           
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        startY = event.getY();
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        float endY = event.getY();

        if (endY > startY) {
            layoutComments.startAnimation(animDown);
            layoutComments.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    }
    return true;
}
```

This function works in an Activity (it's right) but in this component it's not works. I think that the problem is that the layoutComments is inserted in a ViewHolder, but I can't pass the view to the onTouchEvent. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Follow Like this:

```
 public class YourClassName extends Activity
{

   @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {
        .......
        } 

    class FlipAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
            //Now you can access everything from the activity.
    } 
 }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I can't do this because I have a list of layout.....the problem is that I must refer to the exactly ViewHolder, then I must pass the ViewHolder to onTouchEvent. Is it possible?

Comment: http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/02/muftitouch-listview-multi-click.html may be this link will help you.